# Divisibility by prime number

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

Let's say $S=\{P_1,P_2,  P_3\}$ are consecutive primes, $ X=xP_1+yP_2+z P_3 $ where $\{x,y,z\}\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Is it possible to find $x,y \ and \ z$ such that a prime number greater than $P_1,P_2,\ \& \ P_3$ which can divide $X$.

I have check taking some example as $2+3+5=10$ which is not divisible by any prime more than $2, 3, 5$ and failed to find such $\{x,y,z\}$ which satisfies the statement. Please help me to proceed. Thanks for advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question. For example, $3 \cdot 2 + 3 + 5 = 14$, which is divisible by $7$, bigger than $5$. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: $5+7+11=23$ @RossMillikan

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee:  true, but it doesn't change my point because $23$ is divisible by a prime greater than $11$.

Answer (score 0):

The [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) solution shows that any number that is large enough can be expressed as $xP_1+yP_2$.  The largest that cannot be so expressed is $P_1P_2-P_1-P_2-1$, so any number larger than $P_1P_2-P_1-P_2-1+P_3$ can be expressed as you wish.  Taking $5,7,11$ as an example, any number larger than $33$ can be expressed this way.  We have $39=2\cdot 5 + 2 \cdot 7 +11$

Comment: 35 not 39 just so you know as mod 5 shows it's a multiple of 5